# saving music to internal storage in android

Tags: android, kotlin

whate is wrong with this code.
it give me the file with the same size but not supported or corrupted

```
  fun openMusic (activity:Activity,requestcode:Int)
        {
            val intent= Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
            intent.setType("audio/*")
           activity.startActivityForResult(intent,requestcode)
        }
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) 
{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
      
         if(requestCode==MUSIC_REQUEST&&resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK&&data!=null)
        {
            val output=openFileOutput("hamza11.mp3", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val input=contentResolver.openInputStream(data.data)
            val bufferreader=BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(input))
            val bufferedWriter=BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter(output))
            var c=bufferreader.read()
                do{
                    bufferedWriter.write(c)
                    c=bufferreader.read()
                }
                while(bufferreader.read()>=0)
            bufferedWriter.flush()
           
            media= MediaPlayer.create(this,data?.data)
            media.start()
        }
  }
```

I made permission for write external storage

Comment: Define "can't save it".

Comment: it is saved in app internal storage but the the file is invalid